# In Oracle how to clear the missing parenthesis error?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Bill( 
    BillNo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    StoreName VARCHAR2(20) FOREIGN KEY,
    Shopperid INTEGER FOREIGN KEY,
    ArCode CHAR(5) FOREIGN KEY,
    Amount INTEGER,
    BillDate DATE,
    Quantity NUMBER(4) Default 1 Check (Quantity>0)
);
```

Im getting missing paranthesis error.somebody help me with the code?

Comment: Please Tag appropriate database name.

Comment: This isn't MySQL

Comment: @yamuna . . . MySQL does not produce Oracle errors.  I fixed the question.

Comment: The `CHAR` type in Oracle is a blank-padded string provided purely for ANSI completeness, which nobody in their right mind would actually use in production code. The standard string type is called `VARCHAR2`.

Answer (score 1):

The error in MySQL is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR2(20) FOREIGN KEY,
>       Shopperid INTEGER FOREIGN KEY,
>       ArCode CHAR(5) ' at line 3

On the other hand, the error in Oracle is:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Hence, I conclude that you are using Oracle.  The fix is to remove the foreign key references:

```
CREATE TABLE Bill ( 
    BillNo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    StoreName VARCHAR2(20) ,
    Shopperid INTEGER,
    ArCode CHAR(5),
    Amount INTEGER,
    BillDate DATE,
    Quantity NUMBER(4) Default 1 Check (Quantity>0)
);
```

If you want foreign key references, then they might look like:

```
CREATE TABLE Bills ( 
    BillNo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    StoreName FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Stores(StoreName),
    Shopperid FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Shoppers(ShopperId),
    ArCode REFERENCES ArCodes(ArCode),
    Amount INTEGER,
    BillDate DATE,
    Quantity NUMBER(4) Default 1 Check (Quantity>0)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no `varchar2` in mysql. use `varchar`
2. There is no `number`. Use `Decimal`
3. For foreign keys, you need to provide `references` clause to tell exactly what this column is foreign key against.
4. Comma before `Check`

---

This works.

```
CREATE TABLE Bill( 
    BillNo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    StoreName VARCHAR(20),
    Shopperid INTEGER,
    ArCode CHAR(5),
    Amount INTEGER,
    BillDate DATE,
    Quantity decimal(4) Default 1,
    Check (Quantity>0)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for  Oracle DB:

```
CREATE TABLE BILL(
    BILLNO NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    STORENAME VARCHAR2(20) REFERENCES STORE(STORENAME),
    SHOPPERID NUMBER REFERENCES SHOPPER(SHOPPERID),
    ARCODE CHAR(5) REFERENCES ARTICLE(ARCODE),
    AMOUNT NUMBER,
    BILLDATE DATE,
    QUANTITY NUMBER(4) DEFAULT 1 CHECK(QUANTITY > 0)
);
```